# In iPad iOS 11 drop-down issue with xcode 9.

Tags: cordova, ipad, ios11, dropdown

I am getting an random behaviour when taping on select dropdown box in iPad iOS 11.0.1 it appears blank after tapping one time and show again.

I am working on hybrid Cordova application. I runs perfectly when I bulid from xcode 7.3 but with xcode 9 it will show that behaviour.

Please suggest me any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try on adding FastClick in your project**

*FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers. The aim is to make your application feel less laggy and more responsive while avoiding any interference with your current logic.*

more info: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick